# Can I access my original Stack Exchange account even if Google is refusing to log me in?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts

I am asking this question over a different Stack Exchange account, because I cannot access my original account because it's a Google login. You never know when Google wants you to verify your identity. I cannot verify because I do not own a cell phone, and even if I did, I do not trust Google with my cell phone number. Google is denying me access to my account even though I know the password, but can I at least be able to access my original Stack Exchange account?

What should I do in this scenario?

- I would like to access my Stack Exchange account.
- My Stack Exchange account is accessed by a Google login.
- Google is denying me access, even though I know the password, because I need a mobile device to verify my identity.
- When I try logging into Google, I get a message like this.

[image]

Or will I have to just stick with *this new* account, which I created with an email service that's more predictable and doesn't require phone numbers, and lose the progress on the other account?