# What defines the dominant profile information when merging accounts?

Tags: support, profile-page, user-accounts, merge-accounts

I created this account because I [cannot login](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/357871/904178) to my original account. A user suggested merging accounts. This implies combining account data, posts, and reputation. However, I can only have one profile photo, username, or profile description. If I merge 2 accounts where that info differs, what determines which profile will be dominant? Is there a way to choose? Is it random or arbitrary?

Comment: The account with the lower user ID is generally the account that remains.